# google says Your recent app submission was rejected for violating the Device and Network Abuse policy

Tags: android, google-play

i made a fake root (prank) app which shows that it is rooting the device and after some time it shows black screen with one second vibration with logs of unsuccessful root attempt (as if phone has bricked) with a popup that he has been pranked ,thats all i don't understand how this app is violating the Device and Network Abuse policy , and if so how and where is the problem , i want to know so that i can correct my problem or mistake , google has rejected two of my app of which one is this app , anyone please explain me the policy

> Policy Issue: Your app was rejected for violating our Device and Network Abuse policy and sections 4.3 and 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.

i tried mailing them but no response

Comment: Questions about the terms of service of app distribution channels are off-topic for Stack Overflow: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got that rejection for a soundboard for a game. 
Read the policy carefully and notice if there is anything that may cause the rejection.
My advice is that you don't try any other app submission because a few more app rejection and your user will be banned!
It takes a few days to get an answer from Google - it took a few days for me. They sent me a message describing in general what is wrong but I had to go over the policy again to figure it out and it was a copyright issue.
I don't know what may cause the problem but I felt that I had to warn you because I don't want you to get a ban from Google Developer Console. 
Good luck!

Comment: thanks , this is my second app that got rejected , how much rejected app causes ban from Google Developer Console, and if some one got ban , how can he recover from the ban

Comment: I read that the ban is permanently. I think you can only get the user back if you convince Google (by email) that your ban is unfair and then they check your rejections and reply you ( I have done that and they replied that my ban is fair and apparently I won't get the user back).
I uploaded an image of the website Google Developer Console as I'm trying to reach it with the banned user:
http://imgur.com/a/VYnJ8
Hope you will never see that screen.
Good luck!